# How to mock an instance method of an already mocked object?

Tags: ruby, ruby-mocha

I need to mock the following:

```
Class User
  def facebook
    #returns an instance of a facebook gem
  end
end
```

So in my User tests, to access the User's facebook info I need to call `user.facebook.me.info` to retrieve its info. If I want to mock this, I'm currently using the following:

```
@user = Factory(:user)
facebook = mock()
me = mock()
me.expects(:info).returns({"name" => "John Doe"})
facebook.expects(:me).returns(me)
@user.expects(:facebook).returns(facebook)
assert_equal "John Doe", @user.facebook.me.info["name"]
```

This works but seems a bit unwieldy, is there a better way to do this ?

[edit] I'm using mocha as mocking framework

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try something like this :-

```
user = Factory(:user)
user.stubs(:facebook => stub(:me => stub(:info => {:name => "John Doe"})))
```

If you really want to check that all these methods are called (which I suspect you don't), you could do the following :-

```
user = Factory(:user)
user.expects(:facebook => mock(:me => mock(:info => {:name => "John Doe"})))
```

It's a bit more verbose, but it's usually worthwhile giving each mock object a name :-

```
user = Factory(:user)
user.stubs(:facebook => stub('facebook', :me => stub('me', :info => {:name => "John Doe"})))
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: That looks like the cleanest solution out there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to check that all the methods are called, you can also use different alternatives to mocking. For instance, you can use an OpenStruct.

```
@user = Factory(:user)
facebook = mock()
me = mock()
me.expects(:info).returns({"name" => "John Doe"})
facebook.expects(:me).returns(me)
@user.expects(:facebook).returns(facebook)
assert_equal "John Doe", @user.facebook.me.info["name"]
```

becomes

```
@user = Factory(:user)
@facebook = OpenStruct.new(:me => OpenStruct.new(:info => {:name => "John Doe"}))
@user.expects(:facebook).returns(@facebook)
```

This solution also offers you the advantage that you can change the @facebook properties in your tests, if you need to test different conditions.