# Can I add an instance method to a Python "Mock" object?

Tags: python, python-mock

I would like to create a `mock.Mock()` object, then add a method called `session` that acts like an instance method, which is passed a `self` reference to the mock object, allowing the method to add state to the mock object. Is this possible (without manually using `types.MethodType`, e.g., using mock's built-in API), or should I just find a way around it?

Note, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008681/how-to-mock-an-instance-method-of-an-already-mocked-object), which is for Ruby and seems to cover something similar, if not the same thing. Unfortunately, I don't know Ruby very well at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to enhance the capabilities of the `mock.Mock` class, just subclass `Mock` and add your own methods.

```
class MyMock(Mock):
    def session(self):
        # Save session data here?
```

The mock [documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#mock-subclasses-and-their-attributes) explains that when a new mock is to be created, it will be the same type as the parent.  This means that the `session` function will also be available on any other mocks which are created during mocking.

This doesn't cover the case where you need to dynamically attach a `session` function to an existing mock object.

Comment: Thanks, that actually works fine. Although the subclass mimicking the parent part doesn't prove useful in my case, it won't hurt anything.

Answer (score 6):

```
mock_answer = Mock()

def session():
    mock_answer.b = 1

mock_answer.session = session
mock_answer.session()
print(mock_answer.b)  # 1
```

You don't need `self` actually.

Comment: but if you need to use self you could use partial: `from functools import partial` and then `mock_answer.session = partial(session, mock_answer)`